# when using java return vs break

Tags: java

When have the source code like this:

```java
void run() { 
  while (true) {
    if (a > 0) {
    } else {
        return;
    }
  }
}
```

The "else" block has return, but when write down "break;", it also works the same.
So I wonder a little more deep reason why using "return;" is more good code here.

Comment: put some simple output like `System.out.println("Hello");` into that method after your loop and the  run it again with break and return and you will see the difference. One returns from the method, the other just breaks out of the loop.

Comment: depends, do you want to exit the method or do you want to end the loop?

Comment: this code is must stop "run" method.

Answer (score 3):

In this case it works because `break` exits the loop and goes to the end of the method which immediately returns. Which is functionally equivalent to returning immediately.

But in this case, for example

```
void run(){ 
  while(true){
    if(a>0){
    }else{return;}
  }
  System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

vs

```
void run(){ 
  while(true){
    if(a>0){
    }else{break;}
  }
  System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

The first version would not print, the second would